# Clickhouse OPTIMIZE performance for deduplication

Tags: clickhouse

I want to try and understand the performance of the `OPTIMIZE` query in [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/optimize/).

I am planning on using it to remove duplicates right after a bulk insert from a `MergeTree`, hence I have the options of:

`OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table DEDUPLICATE`

or

`OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table FINAL DEDUPLICATE`

I understand that the first state only deduplicates the insert if it hasn't already merged, whereas the second will do it to the whole table. However I am concerned about performance; from dirty analysis of `OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table FINAL DEDUPLICATE` on different size tables I can see it going to get exponentially worse as the table gets bigger (0.1s for 0.1M rows, 1s for 0.3M rows, 12s for 10M rows). I am assuming `OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table DEDUPLICATE` is based however on the insert size and table size, so should be more performative?

Can anyone point to some literature on these performances?

In addition, do these problems go away if I replace the table with a `ReplacingMergeTree`? I imagine the same process will happen under the hood, so doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that:

- ingestion pipeline couldn't be changed to avoid/reduce duplicates?
- duplicates are critical? Do they impact the metric calculation or consume much more disk storage?

Calling of

```sql
OPTIMIZE TABLE db.table FINAL DEDUPLICATE
```

on regular basis is definitely a bad way (it optimizes the **whole** table) - consider restricting the scope of impacted rows (see *PARTITION* param) or columns (see *COLUMNS* param).

I would consider using [only] *ReplacingMergeTree*-engine that was designed to dedupe rows during 'native' merging (not manual as for case with OPTIMIZE).

See the additional info:

- https://www.slideshare.net/Altinity/high-performance-high-reliability-data-loading-on-clickhouse  (slide #27)
- https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/altinity-kb-optimize-vs-optimize-final